# GenericDao with Guice

Tags: generics, guice, typeliteral

I have a interface `DAO<T>`, and a Generic implementation of it (`GenericDAO<T> implements DAO<T>`).

I'll like to do something like this:

```
public interface UserDao extends Dao<User> {
 // code
}

// module
bind(UserDao.class).to(GenericDao.class);
```

Is it possible?
I managed to work a inject of Dao to GenericDao automagically (I didnt create the specific userdao implementation), but, can't get this working...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inject Generic Implementation using Guice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238919/inject-generic-implementation-using-guice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can bind `UserDao` to `GenericDao`. Because `GenericDao` does not implement `UserDao`, albeit both have a common ancestor. If `GenericDao` class has all the methods you need, then you don't need a separate `UserDao` class. You only need a binding as Jeff has written:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<DAO<User>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<GenericDAO<User>>(){});
```

Your client classes will then depend on `DAO<User>`, and they will receive `GenericDAO<User>`. If you do need some `User` entity specific operations, then you should extend `GenericDao<User>`.

I have written a post regarding this [topic](http://jamolkhon.blogspot.com/2012/07/generic-typesafe-dao-with-guice-and.html). Specifically, see the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 3):

You have to ultimately choose a type for `T` in order to actually use the generic class.  For each type you end up using, you need to create a binding like this (using `Integer` for `T`) as an example:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<DAO<Integer>>(){})
   .to(new TypeLiteral<GenericDAO<Integer>>(){});
```