# Guice/Eclipse TypeLiteral issue

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, guice

Here's the issue that I have. I have an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface <AMessageTuple>{

public ConnectableObservable<AMessageTuple> getTokenConnectableObservable();
}
```

And I have an implementation that I wish to be a singleton:

```
public class MyImpl implements MyInterface<ImmutablePair<String, Message>> {

...
//irrelevant members omitted

@Override
public ConnectableObservable<ImmutablePair<String, Message>> getTokenConnectableObservable() {
    return tokenObservable;
}

...
}
```

When I try to bind the interface to the implementation in a class that extends Guice's `AbstractModule`:

```
public class MyServiceModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        TypeLiteral <MyInterface<ImmutablePair<String, Message>>> t = new TypeLiteral<MyInterface<ImmutablePair<String,Message>>>() {
        };  
        bind(t).annotatedWith(Names.named("firstOne")).to(MyImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

the `bind...` ligne gets underlined in red (as compile error) and this is the message I see when hovering over:

> The method `bind(Key<T>)` in the type `AbstractModule` is not applicable
>   for the arguments 
>   `(TypeLiteral<MyInterface<ImmutablePair<String, Message>>>)`

The odd thing is that pressing Ctr+Space does recognize that the method [bind(TypeLiteral)](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#bind-com.google.inject.TypeLiteral-) exists... So am perplexed a bit and hope that someone could give me a hint as to what am I missing.

Context: I am using Eclipse Neon as my IDE, I use (obviously) Guice (version 4.0) for DI and the project's JDK is oracle-7. My current approach on binding generic classes in Guice is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238919/inject-generic-implementation-using-guice).

Comment: did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you use `import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral;`