# Guice binding for generic types not working with ".class"

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

I am trying to bind a Generic class dependencies using Guice

```
public class Myclass<T> {
    @Inject
    public Myclass(Class<T> clazz) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a `Myclass<List<Integer>>` but the binding fails for me

```
private static class ListClassType extends TypeLiteral<Class<List<Integer>>> {}

bind(new ListClassType()).toInstance(List<Integer>.class);
```

But this gives me a compilation error since `List<Integer>.class` is  invalid. Without it I get a runtime exception since Guice is not able to bind generics.

Can someone please help me figure out how to solve the problem? I need to get the binding working.

Comment: check this ,https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239638/2906821, you need to use '`TypeLiteral`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject Generic Implementation using Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238919/inject-generic-implementation-using-guice)