# injector.getInstance of a generic type

Tags: java, class, generics, dependency-injection, guice

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238919/inject-generic-implementation-using-guice) about registering generic type.

example on how to register:

```
 bind(new TypeLiteral<Dal<RoutingResponse>>() {}).to((Class<? extends Dal<RoutingResponse>>) ResponseDal.class);
```

however how can I get an instance of a generic type from the injector?

I have tried:

```
injector.getInstance(Dal<RoutingResponse>().getClass());
```

but got compilation error.

How should I write this?

Comment: I'm actually not sure if it's a duplicate as I don't see a relationship between both snippets you've posted. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581137/injecting-generics-with-guice?rq=1

Comment: rephrased my question.  I 'm sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Key](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Key.html) to get instances of these bindings:

```java
injector.getInstance(new Key<Dal<RoutingResponse>>() {}); // supplied by @DanielPryden in the comments
```

or in a longer version, with a [TypeLiteral](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html):

```java
injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Dal<RoutingResponse>>() {}));
```

Comment: Or just use `Key` directly: `new Key<Dal<RoutingResponse>>() {}` will do the same thing and is shorter.

Comment: Hi I am trying to do something similar, but my generic class has another dep which is injected. For now I have to fetch the dependency and put it in the constructor, is there a way to avoid that?
Code example -
 `Dep dep = injector.getInstance(Dep.class);
 injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Dal<RoutingResponse>>(dep) {}));`
can I simply write it like `injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Dal<RoutingResponse>>(dep) {}));` and let guice handle the DI of dep?