# Dependency injection using Guice with the DAO pattern

Tags: java, generics, types, guice, dao

For a small side project I'm working on I've been trying to implement something of a DAO pattern for my interactions with the DB, and have started using Guice (for my first time) to handle the DI for me. Right now I have this class hierarchy:

[image]

`DAOImpl` takes a reference to a class type so my database client (mongo/morphia) can do some initialization work and instantiate a `BasicDAO` provided by morphia. Here's snippets of the relevant classes:

```
public class DAOImpl<T> implements DAO<T> {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DAOImpl.class);
  private static final String ID_KEY = "id";
  private final org.mongodb.morphia.dao.DAO morphiaDAO;

  @Inject
  public DAOImpl(Datastore ds, Class<T> resourceClass) {
    morphiaDAO = new BasicDAO(resourceClass, ds);

    LOG.info("ensuring mongodb indexes for {}", resourceClass);
    morphiaDAO.getDatastore().ensureIndexes(resourceClass);
  }
}

public class UserDAO extends DAOImpl<User> {
  @Inject
  public UserDAO(Datastore ds) {
    super(ds, User.class);
  }

  public User findByEmail(String email) {
    return findOne("email", email);
  }
}
```

I know that I need to tell Guice to bind the relevant classes for each generic `DAOImpl` that gets extended, but I'm unsure of how to do it. This looks like it might have been answered but it's not clicking for me. I've tried some of the following:

```
public class AppInjector extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(com.wellpass.api.dao.DAO.class).to(DAOImpl.class);

//    bind(new TypeLiteral<SomeInterface<String>>(){}).to(SomeImplementation.class);
//    bind(new TypeLiteral<MyGenericInterface<T>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<MyGenericClass<T>>() {});
//    bind(new TypeLiteral<DAO<User>>() {}).to(UserDAO.class);

    bind(new TypeLiteral<DAO<User>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<DAOImpl<User>>() {});
  }
}
```

These are some of the the errors I've seen:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore was bound.
  while locating org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore
    for the 1st parameter of com.wellpass.api.dao.UserDAO.<init>(UserDAO.java:12)
  at com.wellpass._inject.AppInjector.configure(AppInjector.java:18)

2) java.lang.Class<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
  at com.wellpass.api.dao.DAOImpl.<init>(DAOImpl.java:19)
  at com.wellpass._inject.AppInjector.configure(AppInjector.java:14)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an injection site like the following:

```
@Inject
public DAOConsumer(DAO<User> dao) {
}
```

to be injected with an instance of your `UserDAO` class then

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<DAO<User>>() {}).to(UserDAO.class);
```

is the [correct syntax](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html).

As for your other error:

> 1) No implementation for org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore was bound.

This is because `Datastore` is an interface. You need to bind the interface to an implementation, an instance, or a `Provider<Datastore>`.

To work out how to do this, think of the steps you would need to do this manually without the extra complication of Guice. Once you 100% understand this, you can try and design an object graph that appropriately reflects the steps in the initialization of morphia.

To get you started, the [morphia quick tour](https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.2/getting-started/quick-tour/) has a guide on how to get an instance of the `Datastore` object:

```
final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();

// tell Morphia where to find your classes
// can be called multiple times with different packages or classes
morphia.mapPackage("org.mongodb.morphia.example");

// create the Datastore connecting to the default port on the local host
final Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "morphia_example");
datastore.ensureIndexes();
```

From their code, you can see that there are at least two dependencies required to get the `Datastore`:

1. A singleton `Morphia`
2. A singleton `MongoClient`

You will have to write some code to set this up, possibly using Guice's `Provider` class.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to loop back and say thanks. I started fresh the old fashioned way by manually injecting deps myself and worked my way up to the solution one step at a time. Your answer about the `TypeLiteral` got me most of the way there, but since my `DAO` is an interface which is implemented by `DAOImpl` is what ended up working for me:
`bind(new TypeLiteral<DAOImpl<User>>() {
    }).to(UserDAO.class);
    bind(new TypeLiteral<DAOImpl<Person>>() {
    }).to(PersonDAO.class);

    bind(Mongo.class).to(MongoClient.class);`

Comment: And for the `Datastore`, I ended up making a Provider like you suggested and using the `@Singleton` annotation:
  `@Provides
  @Singleton
  public Datastore datastoreProvider(MongoClient mongoClient, ServerConfig config) {
    Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
    return morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, config.getMongoConfig().getDatabase());
  }`

Comment: @Justin I'm really glad it helped - good luck with the rest of your application!